# Node.js Socket.io ~ On Connection not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I just started working with node.js and socket.io.

bin/www

```
var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('untitled:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

//var server = http.createServer(app);

var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('A new user connected');   <---- Not working 
  });
});

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/jquery/dist')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

The node.js program will work the only thing is that I can not get the print out 'A new user connected' from my console. So it makes me think that there is some problems with my socket.io.

Comment: version of socket.io ?

Comment: @Gaetano socket.io version 1.3.6

Comment: Can you show your client-side code that uses socket.io to connect?

Answer (score 2):

Did you at least include

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
</script>
```

in your client-side html? Otherwise, no connection is openend...

Comment: Quick note for anyone getting started, the documentation on the socket.io getting started is slightly wrong, the listener will not work until you get to the step that includes the above, they need to update the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

try to do 2 things:

1. put server.listen function above call to socket
2. change your call to io like this:

   var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);